# Difference between converting and loading in java?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a question regarding converting and loading in java. If you use e.g. `long='A'`. The Java Virtual Machine Specification at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html specifies this as a conversion. Here the `char` is converted to a `long`.

If, however, a value is in a variable or an array, then Java does not speak any more of converting, but of loading. Here it says that then the array value is loaded and not converted. What I also knew before that if one acts with a variable of another data type that this variable is not converted, but by intermediate steps its information is taken and the information of it is converted, but not the variable. What exactly is the difference between converting and loading as Java describes here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html?

JVMS usage of convert
[image: here Java writes converting]

JVMS usage of load
[image: loading]

Comment: Why *would* it be converting, if you load a `char` value from a variable of type `char`, or from an array of `char` values? What conversion do you think would be done?

Comment: I do not know, but Oracle says that if you have a double, for example, 1.0 it will be converted. So if you have a double by itself and not a double in a variable and in the other case, oracel no longer talks about converting, but only about loading. In contrast to other languages

Comment: Where did Oracle say that "if you have a double it will be converted"? That looks like something that can only make sense in context, but it's missing that context. I'm also not sure what other languages you're referring to where loading a value from a variable or array would always require some kind of conversion.

Comment: `d2f` would be used in `float x = (float) 3.5d` and `daload` would be used in `double x = a[5]` assuming `a` is an array of double.

Comment: Thank you. So for example if you assign something from an int array to a long variable or from a char array to a long variable. Doesn't happen a conversion anymore, but an assignment that loads something? e.g. double=intarray[i].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conversion changes a value from one type to another.

As the documentation for the `d2f` instruction says, a double value on the top of the stack is converted to a float and pushed back onto the stack as a float.

Loading is moving a value of the same type from one place to another, without any changes to the value.

You are talking about JVM instructions, which is what Java is compiled into.

Java performs conversions as needed, for instance:

```
        double d = 1.0;
        float f = (float)d;
```

will cause a conversion from double to float, presumably implemented using the `d2f` instruction above.

```
   double[] a = new double[5];
   double d = a[0];
```

will load a value from a cell in the array to the variable d, but no conversion takes place.

```
   float f = (float)a[0];
```

would perform a conversion.

Comment: Yes, for example I would have an array of doubles and I would initialize a double value form the array with a  loat variable. Java converts or load the value?

Comment: convert and load mean two different thing.  Load means read from memory.

Comment: And what would be, when you are making double[] j = new double[5] and float k=j[i]?

Comment: As per my last example, a conversion from double to float is performed. Of course first we load the double from the array cell.

Comment: But then we do not convert the value directly, but load something first and the loaded is converted. Can we then still say, for example, that the double was converted to float?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain a bit more about what you are trying to understand.

Comment: x = (double) (a+b) would read/load a from memory, read/load b from memory, perform the addition, perform the conversion the result, then write the converted result to memory.  I think you confused load and conversion to be the same thing.  They are not.  Load mean to read from memory.  Conversion means to perform an operation on a value already in memory.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean cheng. If we have a float array[]={2.}; and I say double a=array[0]; . Do I then have a conversion somewhere, from the original float?

Comment: Yes, it would convert float to double.  the VM instruction for that would be f2d.